# MS Outlook: Save and Sort Attachments automatically macro?

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook, email-attachments

I’ve seen a lot of threads about automatically saving attachments from multiple emails to a specific folder.

I would like the destination folder to be variable. I have folders named after employees, and I want their respective attachments to be saved there.

I’m not a coder but I guess the logic of the amendment would be like:

```
saveTo(Folder = contactName);
```

There’s a lot of different VBA code online for the Save Attachments feature that could be used as a base, but I’m not a coder. I’m not sure which program I should refine or how.

If I could just copy and paste the code directly that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble a file path dynamically based on the contact name, see [The Ultimate Guide to VBA String Functions](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/). And I'd suggest learning VBA instead of looking for a ready-made solution, the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article can help you to start quickly.